Тычеть или тыкать?
Увидела в одном тексте выражение "тычеть пальцем". Показалась сомнительным, как будто вариант "тыкать пальцем" более правильный, а "тычеть" до этого слышала только в разговорной речи. Стало интересно, можно ли в принципе так писать в тексте и какой вариант более правильный. Заранее благодарю за ответ.

"Тычеть пальцем" - это диалектное, словарями зафиксированное.

Если художественный текст нуждается в диалектизме, то "тычеть" будет на своём месте.
Однако ему не место в нормативном языке.
[
